# Google Sheets - best combination from list based on criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a list of items with data connected to them and I need the best combination of 3 while multiple criteria based on that data are met.

Here is an example sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-5R0OfJWsjnCUJ9mGKvYuphDRaXeoJZoTsiEdoXi9ag/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you show what result you expect from your sample data and why plz?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if a spreadsheet is the best tool to solve your optimization problem.

You may want to take a look at [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) and see if another tool would serve you better.

If you absolutely want to do this using Google Sheets, see if one of the existing solver add-ons would work for you. Choose **Add-ons > Get add-ons** and search for `solver` to get started.